# File upload from Angular - Set file content to Dto

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I added a IOperationFilter to swagger so that I can test file uploads for my apis from swagger ui. My Dto is like;

```
public class ResourceCreateDto : EntityDto
{

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public IFormFile File { get; set; } //file content here

    public string ExtendedData { get; set; }
}
```

Asp.net Core API is:

```
public async Task<ResourceDto> Create([FromForm] ResourceCreateDto input)
```

This way I can upload file & other data at the same time (Some have suggested to save file 1st and then save data in another call).

What I am not sure is how to use it in Angular end with Abp. Even though proxies are generated how can I get the angular client to use [File] property and post it's data with the rest to server api?

Answer (score 1):

create DTO:

```
export class ResourceCreateDto{
    title : String;
    description: String;
    extendedData : String;
    file: File;
}
```

in html

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="resourceCreateDto.title"/>
<input class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="resourceCreateDto.description"/>
<input class="form-control" type="file" [(ngModel)]="resourceCreateDto.extendedData"/>
<input class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="resourceCreateDto.file" (change)="onChangeFile($event)"/>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" (click)="submit()"> Add new </button>
```

in component

```
    resourceCreateDto: ResourceCreateDto;
    file: any;
    ngOnInit(): void {
        //..
        resourceCreateDto = new ResourceCreateDto();
    }
    onChangeFile(event){
        this.file = event.srcElement.files;
    }
    submit(){
        let formData: FormData = new FormData();
        formData.append('title', this.resourceCreateDto.title  + '');
        formData.append('description', this.resourceCreateDto.description + '');
        formData.append('extendedData', this.resourceCreateDto.extendedData  + '');
        formData.append('file', this.file[0], this.file[0].name);
        // use service call api
        // declare your httpClient
        this.httpClient.post<httpResponse>(`${this.BASEURL}/...`, formData, 
        this.getHttpFileOptions(your token))
        .subscribe(response =>{
            console.log(response);          
        },
        error=>{
            console.log(error);
        })
    }
```

setting option http

```
getHttpFileOptions(token: String): object{
    return {
        observe: 'response',
        responseType: 'json',
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            "Accept": "application/json",
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
        })
    };
}
```

action in server

```
   [HttpPost("Create")]
   public IActionResult Create([FromForm]ResourceCreateDto model, IFormFile File)
```

Hope to help you!